# Where to save public data when External Storage status is "removed"?

Tags: android, storage

I have a device with a "removed" external storage. Is it possible to save data to another public location (where other apps can access)?

Comment: You're sure? [External storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), for most Android 3.0+ devices, is on the same partition as [internal storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). I have not seen an Android 3.0+ device where external storage is located on a removable medium, though I can't rule it out. What device is this?

Comment: Yep, I'm sure. I'm surprised to see it, but I can see in the code that the status for this particular device (a HTC One, Android 4.0.3) is "removed". When I try to view the storage with a 3rd party app (e.g. ES File Explorer) it tells me it's unmounted.

Comment: Check this link http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#setReadable%28boolean%29 it says that setreadable method makes other users make it accessible. may be this is what your looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to save data to another public location (where other apps can access)?

You can save data to the Internet. Otherwise, no, there is no common local storage area other than external storage that would be relevant for your device.